# Allow only one decimal point in a Text Box

Tags: c#, string, parsing, textbox

I am designing a basic calculator using C#. I am facing difficulties while I am entering a decimal point. Example, if I am entering .8 then it gives me 0.8 which is correct if there is nothing on the display screen but after that if I am entering the decimal symbol, then also it accepts it that is 0.8..... I want only one decimal symbol to be accepted for one number. My code is

```
private void btn_Decimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt_Result.Text == "" || LastcharIssymbol==true)
    {
         txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + 0 + ".";
    }
    else
         txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + ".";
}
```

Here, if I am entering 0.9.999 then also it accepts and if I am entering 999..... then also it accepts. I want only one decimal symbol to be accepted for one number that is 999.999. Please help me. Also I am adding two additional labels that can show the current system date and time. I am unable to show the date as well as the time but I am able to show the date and time using VB.Net. I don't know where I am getting the errors. My whole code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CS_Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Boolean LastcharIssymbol {get;set;}
        string op;
        double a, memory;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "1";
            LastcharIssymbol= false;
        }

        private void btn_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "2";
            LastcharIssymbol = false;
        }

        private void btn_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "3";
            LastcharIssymbol = false;
        }

        private void btn_4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "4";
            LastcharIssymbol = false;
        }

        private void btn_5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "5";
            LastcharIssymbol = false;
        }

        private void btn_6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "6";
            LastcharIssymbol = false;
        }

        private void btn_7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "7";
            LastcharIssymbol = false;
        }

        private void btn_8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "8";
            LastcharIssymbol = false;
        }

        private void btn_9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "9";
            LastcharIssymbol = false;
        }

        private void btn_0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + "0";
            LastcharIssymbol = false;
        }

        private void btn_Decimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_Result.Text == "" || LastcharIssymbol==true)
            {
                txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + 0 + ".";
            }
            else
                txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + ".";
        }

        private void btn_Plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(txt_Result.Text=="" || LastcharIssymbol)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter first number to perform the addition operation.");
            }
            else
            {
                op = "+";
                txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + op;
                LastcharIssymbol=true;
            }
        }

        private void btn_Minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_Result.Text == "" || LastcharIssymbol)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter first number to erform the substraction operation.");
            }
            else
            {
                op = "-";
                txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + op;
                LastcharIssymbol = true;
            }
        }

        private void btn_Division_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_Result.Text == "" || LastcharIssymbol)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter first number to perform the division operation.");
            }
            else
            {
                op = "/";
                txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + op;
                LastcharIssymbol = true;
            }
        }

        private void btn_Mult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_Result.Text == "" || LastcharIssymbol)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter first number to perform the multiplication operation.");
            }
            else
            {
                op = "*";
                txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + op;
                LastcharIssymbol = true;
            }
        }

        private void btn_Equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = "";
        }

        private void btn_Clear_All_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = "";
            op = "";
            a = 0;
            memory = 0;
        }

        private void btn_Memory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memory = Convert.ToDouble(txt_Result.Text);
        }

        private void btn_Show_Memory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Result.Text = memory.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One question at a time please. Where are your labels and your date/time code? Please trim the code back. Most of it unnecessary. Please show only what is giving you problems. Also, is this homework?

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have done the calendar to display the date and time. I have written 

    lbl_Time_Disp.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            lbl_Date_Disp.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();

under Form_Load event and under Timer_Tick event I have written 
    lbl_Time_Disp.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

I think this code is correct.

Comment: A suggestion @Pritam, try not to make your question a mess, otherwise people won't read it to the end because it's like a 2000 paged book :)

Comment: Thanks Mehdi, I'll take care of these things in future.

Comment: @Pritam You're welcome my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!txt_Result.Text.Contains("."))
    if(txt_Result.Text == string.Empty)
        txt_Result.Text = "0.";
    else
        txt_Result.Text += ".";
else
    MessageBox.Show("more dots are not allowd");
```

for the case you have text like '11.9+12' which has operations in it you can do the following

```
string formula = "11.9/1.2*99.9+19";

string lastPiece = formula.Split(new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' })[formula.Split(new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' }).Count() - 1];
if (!lastPiece.Contains('.')) formula += ".";
//adds dot

lastPiece = formula.Split(new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' })[formula.Split(new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' }).Count() - 1];

if (!lastPiece.Contains('.')) formula += ".";
//does not add dot

MessageBox.Show(formula);
//output : 11.9/1.2*99.9+19.
```

Comment: Hi Mahdi, Here, if I am performing an operation like 11.9+99.9 then for the second number that is 99.9 it is not accepting the decimal symbol. Please help me. I am new to C#.

Comment: @Pritam it'ok pal ask your questions. well 99.9 already has a `.` why should it accept another one?

Comment: Oh I think got your point just now, You mean your text box contains operations too, right?

Comment: Yes my text box contains operations as well. I hope the answer by Sumit may help.

Comment: @I hope it helps too, my edited answer also works fine. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You should disable the decimal once it is clicked and enable it again if any of the operator or 'C' is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to test whether the string is a valid decimal number. If not, such as if your input has two decimal points, then the TryParse call fails.

TryParse is a good option because there can be many issues with an entered number besides a doubled decimal point such as... a triple decimal point, a misplaced minus sign, alpha chars etc.

Try:

```
private void btn_Decimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal num;
    if (!Decimal.TryParse(txt_Result.Text, out num))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(txt_Result.Text + " is not a valid number.");
        return;
    }

    if (txt_Result.Text == "" || LastcharIssymbol==true)
        txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + 0 + ".";
    else
        txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + ".";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void txtPrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)//textprice key pressed
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && (e.KeyChar != '\b') && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '.')
        {
            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
            int cursorPosLeft = tb.SelectionStart;
            int cursorPosRight = tb.SelectionStart + tb.SelectionLength;
            string result = tb.Text.Substring(0, cursorPosLeft) + e.KeyChar + tb.Text.Substring(cursorPosRight);
            string[] parts = result.Split('.');
            if (parts.Length > 1)
            {
                if (parts[1].Length > 2 || parts.Length > 2)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last `else` to:

```
else if (!txt_Result.Text.Contains (".")) {
    txt_Result.Text = txt_Result.Text + ".";
}
```

Or consider disabling the decimal point button.

You should probably do some validation on the value to ensure it is a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

**Another example , 100% **

```
 private void txtPrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtPrice.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtPrice.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
if (!txt_Result.Text.Contains("."))
if(txt_Result.Text == string.Empty)
    txt_Result.Text = "0.";
else
 MessageBox.Show("Sorry, invalid number format!    
Value can't have more than a decimal point");   
else
txt_Result.Text += ".";
```

Answer (score -2):

Put this code in textbox_keypress
here txtweight is my textbox name you use yours

private void txtweight_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (txtweight.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtweight.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }


    }
```