# Restrict Textbox to 1 decimal place. Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a winform application using c# I have successfully implemented a way to restrict textbox to two decimal places. How can I do it to one decimal place. ?

My code for two decimal places.\

```
private void txtHraRep_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(
                 txtHraRep.Text,
                 "^\\d*\\.\\d{2}$")) e.Handled = true;
            }
            else e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
        }
```

**Changing**  to  "^\d*\.\d{1}$")) e.Handled = true;

**output**

[image: This is the output]

Comment: How about "^\\d*\\.\\d{1}$"

Comment: I tried it earlier. it didnt work. it allowed more than 1 number after decimal.

Comment: Please suggest a way to restrict user from entering not more than 1 value after decimal

Comment: Looks like a job for a MaskedTextBox. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox maybe this would be a better solution?

Comment: Why don't you use numericUpDown and its decimalPlaces property?

Comment: Is ther eany way I can do this uding regex or some other comparison way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow only one decimal point in a Text Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313810/allow-only-one-decimal-point-in-a-text-box)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this without regex by just checking where the decimal separator is in your text and then making sure that is 2 less than the length of the string (1 decimal place and 1 less for array length)

```
var decSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
var idx = txtBasic.Text.IndexOf(decSeparator);
if(idx + 2 >= txtBasic.Text.Length)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `TextBox` control for the input, look at using a `MaskedTextbox` control for your input. This will alleviate any self validation of the input and can show the users what input can be expected of them with messages as to why their input was not correct.

More information about the MaskedTextbox control:
[MaskedTextbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[MaskedTextbox.Mask property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[MSDN Walkthrough: Working with the MaskedTextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kkx4h3az%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(
                 textBox1.Text,
                 "^\\d*\\.\\d{1}$")) e.Handled = true;
            }
            else e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
        }
    }
```

and it worked as it should. It restricted the input to one digit after the decimal point.
But you could enter more than one decimal point and then also more digits.
So you can either try

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || ((e.KeyChar == '.') && (textBox1.Text.IndexOf('.')== -1 )))
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(
                textBox1.Text,
                "^\\d*\\.\\d{1}$")) e.Handled = true;
        }
        else e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
    }
```

or something like

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || ((e.KeyChar == '.') && (textBox1.Text.IndexOf('.')== -1 )))
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.IndexOf('.') > 0)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.IndexOf('.') < textBox1.Text.Length - 1)
                    e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
    }
```

Comment: OK WILL TRY YOUR METHOID LOOKS GOOD TO ME

Answer (score 0):

Create A new TextBox that inherit TextBox like

```
[DefaultBindingProperty("Text")]
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[DefaultEvent("ValueChanged")]
public class SpecializedTextBox : TextBox
{
    private bool _allowNegativeSign = false;
    public bool AllowNegativeSign
    {
        get { return _allowNegativeSign; }
        set { _allowNegativeSign = value; }
    }
    public decimal? DecimalValue
    {
        get
        {
            decimal k;
            if (decimal.TryParse(this.Text, out k))
                return k;
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
                this.Text = value.Value.ToString();
            else
                this.Text = "";
        }
    }
    private void This_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = base.Text;
        int cursorpos = base.SelectionStart;
        bool separatorfound = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; )
            {
                if (char.IsNumber(s[i]))
                    i++;
                else if (AllowNegativeSign && i < System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign.Length && s.StartsWith(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign))
                    i++;
                else if (!separatorfound && s[i].ToString() == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)
                {
                    separatorfound = true;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    s = s.Remove(i, 1);
                    if (i < cursorpos)
                        cursorpos--;
                }
            }
        if (base.Text != s)
        {
            base.Text = s;
            base.SelectionStart = cursorpos;
            base.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
        if (ValueChanged != null)
            ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // SpecializedTextBox
        // 
        this.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.This_TextChanged);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
    public SpecializedTextBox()
        : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

now use this text box and use `DecimalValue` to set or get your value

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
List<string> doubleList = new List<string>(new string[]
        {
            "12345",
            "1234.5",
            "123.45",
            "12.345",
            "1.2345",
            "1.2",
            "1.23",
            "1.234",
            "1.23.45",
            "12.3",
            "123.4",
        }) { };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var x in doubleList)
        {
            int countNumber = Regex.Matches(x, @"[0-9]").Count;
            int countOfDot = Regex.Matches(x, @"\.").Count;

            if (countOfDot == 1 && countNumber != 0) //contains "." and any digit
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
            else if (countOfDot == 0 && countNumber != 0) //not contains "." and any digit
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
            else
            {
               //do nothing . . .
            }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
all except for **1.23.45** (2dots)
```